# C++ Winsock server send a message to every client

Tags: c++, multithreading, server, winsock

How do I turn this echo server into a chat server? What I'd like this program to do is for the server to send every received message to every client. I imagine there should be some sort of a queue, but I am clueless about the realization. Code examples would help a lot. Here is the code:

Server:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct CLIENT_INFO
{
    SOCKET hClientSocket ;
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddr ;
} ;

char szServerIPAddr[ ] = "192.168.1.221" ;     // Put here the IP address of the server
int nServerPort = 5050 ;                    // The server port that will be used by
                                            // clients to talk with the server

bool InitWinSock2_0( ) ;
BOOL WINAPI ClientThread( LPVOID lpData ) ;

int main( )
{
    if ( ! InitWinSock2_0( ) )
    {
        cout << "Unable to Initialize Windows Socket environment" << WSAGetLastError( ) << endl ;
        return -1 ;
    }

    SOCKET hServerSocket ;

    hServerSocket = socket(
        AF_INET,        // The address family. AF_INET specifies TCP/IP
        SOCK_STREAM,    // Protocol type. SOCK_STREM specified TCP
        0               // Protoco Name. Should be 0 for AF_INET address family
        ) ;
    if ( hServerSocket == INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
        cout << "Unable to create Server socket" << endl ;
        // Cleanup the environment initialized by WSAStartup()
        WSACleanup( ) ;
        return -1 ;
    }

    // Create the structure describing various Server parameters
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr ;

    serverAddr . sin_family = AF_INET ;     // The address family. MUST be AF_INET
    serverAddr . sin_addr . s_addr = inet_addr( szServerIPAddr ) ;
    serverAddr . sin_port = htons( nServerPort ) ;

    // Bind the Server socket to the address & port
    if ( bind( hServerSocket, ( struct sockaddr * ) &serverAddr, sizeof( serverAddr ) ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        cout << "Unable to bind to " << szServerIPAddr << " port " << nServerPort << endl ;
        // Free the socket and cleanup the environment initialized by WSAStartup()
        closesocket( hServerSocket ) ;
        WSACleanup( ) ;
        return -1 ;
    }

    // Put the Server socket in listen state so that it can wait for client connections
    if ( listen( hServerSocket, SOMAXCONN ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        cout << "Unable to put server in listen state" << endl ;
        // Free the socket and cleanup the environment initialized by WSAStartup()
        closesocket( hServerSocket ) ;
        WSACleanup( ) ;
        return -1 ;
    }

    // Start the infinite loop
    while ( true )
    {
        // As the socket is in listen mode there is a connection request pending.
        // Calling accept( ) will succeed and return the socket for the request.
        SOCKET hClientSocket ;
        struct sockaddr_in clientAddr ;
        int nSize = sizeof( clientAddr ) ;

        hClientSocket = accept( hServerSocket, ( struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, &nSize ) ;
        if ( hClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET )
        {
            cout << "accept( ) failed" << endl ;
        }
        else
        {
            HANDLE hClientThread ;
            struct CLIENT_INFO* clientInfo = (struct CLIENT_INFO*) malloc(sizeof(struct CLIENT_INFO)) ;
            DWORD dwThreadId ;
            clientInfo -> clientAddr = clientAddr ;
            clientInfo -> hClientSocket = hClientSocket ;

            cout << "Client connected from " << inet_ntoa( clientAddr . sin_addr ) << endl ;

            // Start the client thread
            hClientThread = CreateThread( NULL, 0,
                ( LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE ) ClientThread,
                ( LPVOID ) &(*clientInfo), 0, &dwThreadId ) ;
            if ( hClientThread == NULL )
            {
                cout << "Unable to create client thread" << endl ;
            }
            else
            {
                CloseHandle( hClientThread ) ;
            }
        }
    }

    closesocket( hServerSocket ) ;
    WSACleanup( ) ;
    return 0 ;
}

bool InitWinSock2_0( )
{
    WSADATA wsaData ;
    WORD wVersion = MAKEWORD( 2, 0 ) ;

    if ( ! WSAStartup( wVersion, &wsaData ) )
        return true ;

    return false ;
}

BOOL WINAPI ClientThread( LPVOID lpData )
{
    CLIENT_INFO *pClientInfo = ( CLIENT_INFO * ) lpData ;
    char szBuffer[ 1024 ] ;
    int nLength ;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        nLength = recv( pClientInfo -> hClientSocket, szBuffer, sizeof( szBuffer ), 0 ) ;
        if ( nLength > 0 )
        {
            szBuffer[ nLength ] = '\0' ;
            cout << "Received " << szBuffer << " from " << inet_ntoa( pClientInfo -> clientAddr . sin_addr ) << endl ;

            // Convert the string to upper case and send it back, if its not QUIT
            strupr( szBuffer ) ;
            if ( strcmp( szBuffer, "QUIT" ) == 0 )
            {
                closesocket( pClientInfo -> hClientSocket ) ;
                return TRUE ;
            }
            // send( ) may not be able to send the complete data in one go.
            // So try sending the data in multiple requests
            int nCntSend = 0 ;
            char *pBuffer = szBuffer ;

            while ( ( nCntSend = send( pClientInfo -> hClientSocket, pBuffer, nLength, 0 ) != nLength ) )
            {
                if ( nCntSend == -1 )
                {
                    cout << "Error sending the data to " << inet_ntoa( pClientInfo -> clientAddr . sin_addr ) << endl ;
                    break ;
                }
                if ( nCntSend == nLength )
                    break ;

                pBuffer += nCntSend ;
                nLength -= nCntSend ;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error reading the data from " << inet_ntoa( pClientInfo -> clientAddr . sin_addr ) << endl ;
        }
    }

    return TRUE ;
}
```

Client:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char szServerIPAddr[ 20 ] = "192.168.1.221" ;     // Put here the IP address of the server
int nServerPort = 5050 ;                    // The server port that will be used by                                            // clients to talk with the server

bool InitWinSock2_0( ) ;

int main( )
{
    cout << "Enter the server IP Address: " ;
    cin >> szServerIPAddr ;
    cout << "Enter the server port number: " ;
    cin >> nServerPort ;

    if ( ! InitWinSock2_0( ) )
    {
        cout << "Unable to Initialize Windows Socket environment" << WSAGetLastError( ) << endl ;
        return -1 ;
    }

    SOCKET hClientSocket ;

    hClientSocket = socket(
        AF_INET,        // The address family. AF_INET specifies TCP/IP
        SOCK_STREAM,    // Protocol type. SOCK_STREM specified TCP
        0               // Protoco Name. Should be 0 for AF_INET address family
        ) ;
    if ( hClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
        cout << "Unable to create Server socket" << endl ;
        // Cleanup the environment initialized by WSAStartup()
        WSACleanup( ) ;
        return -1 ;
    }


    // Create the structure describing various Server parameters
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr ;

    serverAddr . sin_family = AF_INET ;     // The address family. MUST be AF_INET
    serverAddr . sin_addr . s_addr = inet_addr( szServerIPAddr ) ;
    serverAddr . sin_port = htons( nServerPort ) ;

    // Connect to the server
    if ( connect( hClientSocket, ( struct sockaddr * ) &serverAddr, sizeof( serverAddr ) ) < 0 )
    {
        cout << "Unable to connect to " << szServerIPAddr << " on port " << nServerPort << endl ;
        closesocket( hClientSocket ) ;
        WSACleanup( ) ;
        return -1 ;
    }

    char szBuffer[ 1024 ] = "" ;

    while ( strcmp( szBuffer, "QUIT" ) != 0 )
    {
        cout << "Enter the string to send (QUIT) to stop: " ;
        cin >> szBuffer ;

        int nLength = strlen( szBuffer ) ;

        // send( ) may not be able to send the complete data in one go.
        // So try sending the data in multiple requests
        int nCntSend = 0 ;
        char *pBuffer = szBuffer ;

        while ( ( nCntSend = send( hClientSocket, pBuffer, nLength, 0 ) != nLength ) )
        {
            if ( nCntSend == -1 )
            {
                cout << "Error sending the data to server" << endl ;
                break ;
            }
            if ( nCntSend == nLength )
                break ;

            pBuffer += nCntSend ;
            nLength -= nCntSend ;
        }

        strupr( szBuffer ) ;
        if ( strcmp( szBuffer, "QUIT" ) == 0 )
        {
            break ;
        }

        nLength = recv( hClientSocket, szBuffer, sizeof( szBuffer ), 0 ) ;
        if ( nLength > 0 )
        {
            szBuffer[ nLength ] = '\0' ;
            cout << "Received " << szBuffer << " from server" << endl ;
        }
    }

    closesocket( hClientSocket ) ;
    WSACleanup( ) ;
    return 0 ;
}

bool InitWinSock2_0( )
{
    WSADATA wsaData ;
    WORD wVersion = MAKEWORD( 2, 0 ) ;

    if ( ! WSAStartup( wVersion, &wsaData ) )
        return true ;

    return false ;
}
```

Comment: "_How do I turn this echo server into a chat server?_" By writing code that does that. SO is not a code writing service, nor it is a tutorial service. What is your, specific, question?

Answer (score 0):

Just for giving the idea (if you need further help, implement your server and ask new, more specific questions on this site):

- First, create an appropriate message queue. Side note: `std::vector` has the disadvantage that you are moving data around all the time on either inserting or removing messages (depending how you implement it). Some kind of ring buffer is more efficient - it could be implemented based on a std::vector, though.
- Create another queue containing all the connected clients. Either re-use your ring-buffer (them make it a template), or, as changes are less frequent, just use an std::vector.
- Create a thread that reads from the first message from the queue and sends it to all the clients in the list. You might use a [std::condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to let your thread sleep entirely while the queue is empty and wake up as soon as some data is inserted.
- For every `accept`ed connection, create a new thread reading from the socket and place the accepted data into the queue.

Be aware that you need to protect both message queue and clients list against race conditions as both are accessed from multiple threads!